# Control a file name in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have the following javascript code:

```
fileName = "Report_" + Name + ".csv"
var hiddenElement = document.createElement('a');
hiddenElement.href = 'data:attachment/text,' + encodeURI(data);
hiddenElement.target = '_self';
hiddenElement.download = fileName;
window.open(hiddenElement.href, "My Report", "width=800, height=200", true);
```

The downloaded file name is "download", instead the value of `fileName` variable. Is anyone know what the issue?

Comment: Note that `hiddenElement` is effectively just being used as a storage location to hold your link - the only thing you're using from it is the `href` property in the call to `window.open`.  Setting the `target` and `download` properties is doing nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file name is controlled by the "Content-Disposition" response header set by the server.

For example if you want your file name to be "test.txt" then you need to set the header to:

```
Content-Disposition:attachment;filename="test.txt"
```

Some but not all browsers support the download attribute on anchor elements. Notably Safari and IE do not yet support this feature e.g.

```
<a href="Report_foo.csv" download="Report_bar.csv">Download Report</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is `Content-Dispositio` something i can just paste into my code? I've tired it and got `Unexpected token :` error.

Comment: Setting a response header such as Content-Disposition is something that is done server side. How you set a response header depends on the language and framework you are using on your webserver.

Answer (score 2):

The HTML 5 has a 'a download' which allows you to rename a file

```
<a download="name.txt" href="originalFileName.txt">Click here to download</a>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Only other solution is to do it on the server side by setting the Content-Disposition of the file.

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=somecustomname.txt
```

Comment: Last time I checked there wasn't broad support for the download attribute on an anchor. Specifically not supported by IE and Safari.

Comment: @bhspencer - I agree (however, it's slowly getting there - you can check the compability list here: http://caniuse.com/#feat=download ), hence, the second part of my answer